# Java Concurrency: Count characters of String

Tags: java, multithreading, counting

while doing some Java practice, I came upon a task including multithreading and concurrency. I have **absolutely no experience** with that so far. The foundation is a java class/program, which has a function to count characters in a string. The function is provided with the string and a ConcurrentHashMap with the alphabet in lowercase (each char as key) and the occurence of each char as value (as integer). The program works (with Hashmap and no multithreading, meaning without implementing runnable and without  the public void run).

I understand the usage of ConcurrentHashMap in order to enable multithreading and thus implemented ConcurrentHashMap (using it instead of HashMap). Furthermore I know, that my class needs to implement runnable, and thus has a public void run () method.

### My aim:

I would like to know, how to start three threads, which all count the character's occurences of the same String and write it into the ConcurrentHashMap.

Am I right, that one utilizes this kind of implementation to make the program run faster? (answered)

### Further information

As understood from the answers, it is not clear, why one would do this. It is a practice task. Later on, I might add file-input of large text-files (or might not, it is practice, I do not know).

### Final edit

So, it is not useful for this purpose to do multithreading. No further answers needed.

### My Code so far:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

class WordCounter implements Runnable {

    // method to count characters in given string
    static void characterCount(String inputString, ConcurrentHashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap) {
        // Converting String to lowercase
        inputString = inputString.toLowerCase();

        // Converting given string to char array
        char[] strArray = inputString.toCharArray();

            // checking each char of strArray
            for (char c : strArray) {
                if (charCountMap.containsKey(c)) {
                    // If char is present in charCountMap,
                    // incrementing it's count by 1
                    charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.get(c) + 1);
                }
            }

            // Printing the charCountMap
            for (Map.Entry entry : charCountMap.entrySet()) {
                if(!entry.getValue().equals(0)){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
            }}

    }


    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creating a HashMap containing alphabet in lower case
        // as a key and occurrences as  a value (initialized with value: 0)
        ConcurrentHashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap
                = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch)
            charCountMap.put(ch, 0);

        String str = "GGACACGTagGcGT";
        characterCount(str, charCountMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of creating a histogram for the same string three times?

Comment: It is from a practice task, I thought it would mean, that, instead of having one thread counting (the main thread), I would initialize three threads, which all count and write to the ConcurrentHashMap, so it is faster? I also asked in my question, if this is meant for performance enhancement. Please read carefully, before you downvote :(  (I know nothing of multithreading so far, I only read some basic guides and googled mulithread/count things but could not find any satisfying answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one question I saw in your question:

> Am I right, that one utilizes this kind of implementation to make the program run faster?

No, not in this case. You have to understand that creating and starting threads, and then *synchronizing* them somehow to avoid race conditions (to achieve correct, deterministic behavior) doesn't come for free.

Threads are resources of the underlying operating system. It takes *time* to create, start, manage them.

Therefore: using multiple threads does not automatically translate into "my program runs faster". Multiple threads only make things "faster" when the advantage of processing data in parallel gains more than the initial cost of creating these threads. And of course, you also need hardware able to run threads in parallel. *If* your hardware would be able to run only one thread at time, then doing stuff that only uses the CPU (and never waits for some external input) then having multiple threads would *always* be slower.

Now, your task is to count the characters in a short string, provided by a human user. This is most quickly solved by a single thread iterating the string, and doing its work. Thus: most likely, your multi threaded program will be quite a bit slower compared to a straight forward single threaded solution.

If, on the other hand your task would be to read thousands of files, with millions of lines of text, for example to build some sort of index for a full text search, then of course: using multiple threads can dramatically speed up overall execution time.

Beyond that: the code you have written so far does nothing. To make a reasonable program you would need to:

- have some code in that `run()` method.
- to then create multiple threads that invoke that `run()` method in parallel

Of course, that *also* requires you to reasonable *partition* your data. For example, you could have each thread count a specific *sub string* of your input.

Comment: I think, the program will be upscaled later. The basic counting example is for the letters a,c,g and t. The genetic code, so to speak, which can be quite bigger. But i wanted to start small in order to understand the principle of how to do this. I only found examples for e.g. counting up to 1000 with three threads and then ending, which somehow is not what I want

Comment: @Shushiro But that is not what you asked about. You see, I answered the one *question* you have in your input to us. I updated the question a bit to further guide your work, but then: this is not a tutor service. We help with specific questions, not with "I have a vision, how do I get there from here".

Comment: I see, this was not precise enough and wanted too much

Comment: @Shushiro Yes. But I appreciate the quick accept. My suggestion: when you have specific questions on *how to* things, then write up smaller questions. One aspect per question, step by step.